# Sending data/obb to external SD card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I had a phone with CM11 and I was used to having an option, on the app detail screen, to send an app to the SD card. Now I have bought a new phone, with near-stock firmware (4.4.2), and that option is missing. The phone only has 8Gb of internal storage (~5.5 after OS), so I really need to move some larger apps (San Andreas for instance) to the external SD card (32Gb C10). Is there a straightforward way to do this? I am rooted and I have xposed installed, but I can't find any simple solution to my problem.

I could technically manually move the relevant data/* or obb/* to the external SD and use Lucky Patcher or some tool to bind folders, but this seems like such an important point (with 1-2Gb games being common; how I am supposed to install Bard's tale?) that I wonder if there is a simple tool to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As your device is rooted, and you even have Xposed running on it, you have a pool of choices – e.g. [Obb on SD](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.smartmadsoft.xposed.obbonsd) would probably be your first choice, as it exactly matches your requirements. It lets you move all or only selected OBB to the *external* SD card. There are several alternatives; be welcome to check [my list of helpers with storage media](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_535) for that.

Answer (score 1):

If your rooted you can make system link or make data partition for sd and mount it.
system link will be easy solution. ln -s command will do the job.
Careful you may not able to start phone in case of storage card(mmc) is removed or corrupted.

second method for easy steps is check magisk custom module method to mount your own obb /data/data every booting.